# How to get DocumentSnapshot from Fb Firestore with the given groupId

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to get all the info in my Fb firestore. By the given `groupId` I have get the DocumentSnapshot though the groupModel but I don’t know how to write the documentSnapshot and display it on the screen.

**Get documentSnapshot though the GroupModel:**

```
Future<String> joinGroup(String groupId, userUid) async {
    String retVal = "error";
    List<String> members = [];
    try {
      members.add(userUid);
      await _firestore.collection("groups").doc(groupId).update({
        'members': FieldValue.arrayUnion(members),
      });
      await _firestore.collection("users").doc(userUid).update({
        'groupId': groupId,
      });
      await _firestore.collection("users").doc(userUid).update({
        'groupName': '_none',
      });
      await _firestore.collection("users").doc(userUid).update({
        'groupLeader': '',
      });
      //Push the DocSnapshot though the GroupModel Right HERE
      // Want to Snapshot everything and display the "name" on the firstScreen
     _firestore
        .collection('groups')
        .doc(groupId)
        .snapshots()
        .map((docSnapshot) => GroupModel.fromDocumentSnapshot(doc: docSnapshot));
      retVal = "success";
    } catch (e) {
      // ignore: avoid_print
      print(e);
    }
    return retVal;
  }
```

**GroupModel (some of it):**

```
factory GroupModel.fromDocumentSnapshot({required DocumentSnapshot<Map<String,dynamic>> doc}) {
    return GroupModel(
      id: doc.id,
      name: (doc.data() as Map<String, dynamic>)["name"],
      leader: (doc.data() as Map<String, dynamic>)["leader"],
      members: List<String>.from((doc.data() as Map<String, dynamic>)["members"]),
      groupCreate: (doc.data() as Map<String, dynamic>)["groupCreate"],
    );
```

**Fb firestore:**
[image]
I want to display the "name" (Phil)

(firstScreen)**This is what I get so far (But still doesn’t work.) Maybe you can point out what’s wrong.  :**

```
late final groupId = GroupModel(
      id: groupId.id,
      name: 'name',
      leader: 'leader',
      members: ['members'],
      groupCreate: Timestamp.now());

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
        stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection('groups')
            .doc(groupId.id)
            .snapshots(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.data == null) {
            return Container();
          }
          return Text((snapshot.data as DocumentSnapshot)['name']),
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is with the group id, it would help if you could send the entire file where you are reciving the error.